# Generar un código con varios campos de una tabla dinámica

Tags: javascript, tabla-dinámica

Tengo una tabla dinámica en donde puedo insertar filas o eliminarlas. En uno de las columnas debo de mostrar el resultado de generar un código en base al valor de varios campos de cada fila de dicha tabla según de vayan añadiendo, de modo que se queden almacenados en forma de un array bidimensional que luego será recorrido tanto para validar dichos campos de la tabla como de enviarlos a una base de datos. El problema que tengo, es que no doy con la solución para que, una vez creado el código(lo he creado sin problemas), llegue al campo de la fila, desde donde ha sido llamado una vez pulsado el botón de "agregarfila". Solo consigo generar el de la primera fila pero no de las que voy añadiendo a la tabla. Tampoco se como insertar el valor de retorno desde la función javascript hasta la tabla. Agradezco una ayuda.

```js
function Cod_AFila_Puno(){
      codmenuno ();    
      agregarFilaplatouno();  
}

function codmenuno () {  
var ndia = document.getElementById("diapuno").value;
var nord = document.getElementById("iduno").value;
var txt1 = "D";
var txt2= "-";
var txt3= "P";
var plato= "1";
var txt4= "-";

var codpuno = txt1.concat(ndia,txt2,txt3,plato,txt4,nord);
// alert('el codigo es :' + codpuno);
return codpuno ; 
}

function agregarFilaplatouno(){
document.getElementById("tablaMenus1").insertRow(-1).innerHTML =
'<td><div class="size"><input id="iduno" class="iduno" type=text name="iduno[]"/></div></td><td><div class="size2"><input id="platouno" class="platouno" type=text name="platouno[]"/></div></td><td><div class="size2"><input id="codpuno" class="codpuno"  type=text name="codpuno[]"/></div></td>';
}
function eliminarFilaplatouno(){
  var table = document.getElementById("tablaMenus1");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length; 
  if(rowCount <= 1)
    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado'); 
  else
    table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
                       }
```

```html
<form name="Actualizar" action="" method="POST">
<h2 class="text-center">Gestión y Edición de Menús</h2>
<div class="container" >
 <div class="menus-form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
         <table border="1" class="table" id="tablaMenus1">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
         <th style="background-color:#5cb85c"><div>Dia/Cena Num</div></th>
         <td><div class="size2"><input id="diapuno" style=" height: 28px;" maxlength="2" max="15" min="1" class="diapuno" placeholder="Elije" type=number name="diapuno[]" value=""/></div></td>
         
         <tr>    
               <th style="background-color:red"><div class="size">Id1</div></th>
               <th style="background-color:yellow"><div class="size2">1ºPlato</div></th>   
               <th style="background-color:red"><div class="size">Codigo</div></th>
        </tr>   
     
         <tr>
  
<td><div class="size"><input id="iduno" class="iduno"  type=text  name="iduno[]" value="" </div></td>
<td><div class="size2"><input id="platouno" class="platouno"  type=text name="platouno[]"  value=""/></div></td>
<td><div class="size2"><input id="codpuno" class="codpuno"  type=text name="codpuno[]"  value=""/></div></td> 
         </tr>
           </thead>
      </table>
   
      
           <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" onclick="Cod_AFila_Puno()">Agregar Fila</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-2" onclick="eliminarFilaplatouno()">Eliminar Fila</button>
           </div>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</form>
```

Comment: Del lado del servidor existen funciones que te ayudan a hashear, codificar o encriptar si es lo que necesitas estos valores, entonces creo que no deberias enfocarte en codificarlos ahora mismo desde js si no desde el lado del servidor, por ejemplo si usas php esta la funcion hash que te permite encodificar un valor usando algún metodo de codificación como sha512, o la funcion md5 que te da una codificacion en md5 un poco mas insegura pero mas corta. considera entonces en vez de encriptar o codificar la información del lado del cliente, codificarla y verificarla del lado del servidor.

Comment: @ Riven. No, quizás no me explicado bien. No quiero encriptar nada. Si observas en el script de java ya creo ese código (por llamarlo de alguna manera) concatenando cadenas de texto y el valor de dos campos que vienen de la tabla "diapuno" y "iduno" .

Comment: Lo que quiero es devolver el código generado que llamo "codpuno" (en JS)  e insertarlo en el imput de la tabla del formulario "codpuno[]" y en su correspondiente fila. La tabla sirve para  insertar y guardar posteriormente los registros en la base de datos de forma dinámica varios platos de comida  por día, así pues, deben de quedar registrados por día cada plato mediante una id, el nombre del plato y su código, este último es el objeto del problema. Espero haber sido un poco mas claro.